# Elements interfering with adjacent element causing it to be hidden

Tags: html, css

I have the below code that is displaying cross fading flight numbers and next to them, a time. Yet this time element is not displaying in the correct position, therefore being covered by a separate element and hidden.
I cannot see why the cross fading elements are causing the issue.

```
<div id='p1r0' class='cell sdrow' style='top:3px;'>

    <div class='cell sp2'> </div>

    <div id='p1r0flts' class='cell  flts' style='top:0px;position:absolute;'>
        <div class='cell' style='top:0px;position:absolute;'>
            <div id='p1r0flts1' class='cell flts xfader_1'>LM234</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cell' style='top:0px;position:absolute;'>
            <div id='p1r0flts0' class='cell flts xfader_0'>FR1234</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='cell time'>11:30</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.flts{
    left: 238px;
    width: 250px;
    color: White;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: SkyBlue;
}

.time{
    left: 488px;
    width: 200px;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
}

.sdrow{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1920px;
    max-height: 100px;

}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have added positioning of relative and absolute but this changed nothing.
The below code without crossfade does not interfere with the time node:

```
<div class='cell flts' style='background-color:LightSlateGray;'>GMAJY</div>


<div class='cell time'>11:50</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of current layout]

Comment: Have you tried setting the times parent nodes position to relative and times to absolute?

Comment: Also, the time node doesn’t appear to have a parent. Is it meant to be inside your cell node?

Comment: Can you post an image of how it should look?

Comment: _"I cannot see why the cross fading elements are causing the issue"_ - currently probably _because_ they are absolute positioned, because that takes them out of the layout flow - they wont influence the height of their parent any more, or the position of following elements. But we can't currently tell, if that was the original code already, or if you added that in your attempt to fix things now.

Comment: The time node is separate to the flights node. They are two separate columns However they are all within a parent row element. I will update the question with further code

Comment: how should it look like? can you give a rough sketch? i will work on it...

Comment: I would use flex on the parent (sdrow) and remove the absolute positioning on the children

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what this is supposed to look like. The 11:50 time is displaying correctly. The time above is not as the flight numbers are cross fading. Thank you for taking the time with this. I will give using flex a try as well.

Comment: Ok, thank you for image. what should cross fade here? the time with the flight number?

Comment: Just the flight numbers. The time is completely static.

Comment: Using flex on the P1R0Flts has solved the issue! Much appreciated everyone, had not heard of flex before.

Comment: I have another question on my account regarding other crossfade animations in this program, that all display on top of each other when the page is first loaded. Would anyone be able to look into this as well? been stuck for a while on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'Flex' instead of 'Absolute' positioning on the flights column has solved the issue. Code as below:

```
<div id='p1r0flts' class='cell  flts' style='top:0px;position:flex;'>
    <div class='cell' style='top:0px;position:absolute;'>
        <div id='p1r0flts1' class='cell flts xfader2_1'>
        LM234</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell' style='top:0px;position:absolute;'>
        <div id='p1r0flts0' class='cell flts xfader2_0'>
        FR1234</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class='cell time'>11:30</div>
```